# Got second order gradient computation issue in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Recently I am implement Gradient penalty Wasserstein GAN. And I got an issue:

> ValueError: No attr named '_XlaCompile' in name:
>   "gradients/model_2_2/flatten_1/ Reshape_grad/Reshape" op: "Reshape"
>   input: "gradients/model_2_2/dense_2/MatMul_grad/MatMul" input:
>   "gradients/model_2_2/flatten_1/Reshape_grad/Shape" device:
>   "/device:GPU:0" attr {   key: "T"   value {
>       type: DT_FLOAT   } } attr {   key: "Tshape"   value {
>       type: DT_INT32   } }

I seems this part of gradient computing is somehow missing or sth. I did use reshape in the TensorFlow Graph. Someone got similar issues?

Comment: Are you trying to use XLA? Maybe remove that, and see if it still works. More context around the code would also help.

Comment: I am not trying to use XLA... somehow I got this kind of error. But I have solved my problem by replacing keras cropping layer with tf.slice. (I mix keras and tensorflow to build my model)

BTW, thanks!